# How to optimize a parameter validation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, optimization

I have one very interesting question.

We know that we should check every parameter in a function.

So we want to check : if param exists,  if type is correct, if it is contain some property in case of JSON type etc.  and it should be done in every function.

actually how we can optimize and and avoid a tons of   conditional  if-else?

I tried to do something like that, but I don't know if it's good. Because it just throws an error and stops a program. But I don't know how it can be done better. I thought that es7 decorators will help me but it isn't because I can't use it for the properties checking because it works only with classes and methods.

```
export function isExists(param) {
    if (param) {
        return true;
    }
    throw new TypeError("Param should exists. Please check it.");
}

export function isJsonObject(itemToTest) {
    if (itemToTest) {
        return ~Object.prototype.toString.call(itemToTest).search(/Object/);
    }
    throw new TypeError("itemToTest should exists if you want to test it. Please check it.");
}

export function isOwnPropertyExist(objToTest, propName) {
    isExists(objToTest); // Here i want to continue a program workflow or it will be broken if my checking won't have success
    isExists(prop);

    isJsonObject(objToTest);

    if (objToTest.hasOwnProperty(propName)) {
        return true;
    }
    throw new TypeError("objToTest should exists and contains a property with name ");
}
```

Thanks for any help!  This question is tormenting me a more than 2 years.
P.S. I don't want to use Typescript (I just want to know, how do you resolve this moment)

Comment: TypeScript is exactly the sort of thing which would really help you here. What exactly are your reservations against it?

Comment: Because my project works with a native js, unfortunately.

Comment: How about [contracts.js](http://www.contractsjs.org/)?

Comment: "Works with native js"… well, Typescript in the end does compile to "native JS". You're asking us how to write code differently to solve your issues with, essentially, type safety. You *could* simply start adding a few type hints here and there to start enforcing your types correctly, and then compile it through Typescript to get "native JS". That's not fundamentally different than writing lots `is...()` everywhere; you just introduce the additional workflow step of TS compilation. If at all feasible, moving to TS is probably the best you can do here.